# How to track an unregistered google beacon?

Tags: google-chrome

I received a Google Beacon about a year ago. That is a small bluetooth device which can track business visitors.

It never occurred to me to register it because it said that it only needs taking out of the box to be activated which I did and glued it to the back wall of my van. And I forgot about it.

On Monday this week my van was stolen. I went to Google Beacon Dashboard to see if I can locate the beacon on Google Maps but it asks to register it before I can do anything.

I was wondering, does Google know what beacon they sent me and can they locate it despite it being unregistered?

Please, it would be really helpful if it was possible.

Comment: Do you still have the box / documentation? Does it have the required information / IDs on it?

Comment: Nope, and the van was recovered with engine removed.

Comment: Bah, sorry to hear that...